# Angular4 canActivate and google firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I am experiencing a problem with my Angular 4 app and the canActivate guard when using firebase.

I have this service AuthService which links to firebase.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authState: any = null;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private db: AngularFireDatabase,private router:Router) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
      this.authState = auth
    });

    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if(user){
        console.log('user signed in');
      }
      else{
        this.anonymousLogin();
      }
    })
  }

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authState !== null;
  }

  get currentUser(): any {
    return this.authenticated ? this.authState : null;
  }

  get currentUserAnonymous(): boolean {
    return this.authenticated ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false;
  }

  //// Google Auth ////
  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    return this.socialSignIn(provider);
  }
  private socialSignIn(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((credential) =>  {
          this.authState = credential.user
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  //// Anonymous Auth ////
  anonymousLogin() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
    .then((user) => {
      this.authState = user
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  //// Email/Password Auth ////
  emailLogin(email:string, password:string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        this.authState = user
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  //// Sign Out ////
  signOut(): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }
}
```

and this is my guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if(this.auth.authState && !this.auth.currentUserAnonymous){
        console.log('User is staff');
        return true;
      }
      else{
        console.log(this.auth.authState);
        console.log(this.auth.currentUserAnonymous);
        console.log('User is not staff')
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      }
  }
}
```

The guard works fine when you navigate to the guarded component using a link from another component  when the user is logged but when you attempt to go directly to the guarded component using the address bar it logs the following

```
auth.guard.ts:20 null  <-- this.auth.authState
auth.guard.ts:21 false <-- this.auth.currentUserAnonymously
auth.guard.ts:22 User is not staff
auth.service.ts:19 user signed in
```

since it logs 'user signed in' from the auth service after the guard it seems it means the auth.service is checking the logged in status after the guard. How do I change this to do the service first? Or do I need to do call the service from the guard? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with AngularFireAuth but you need to have the canActivate return the this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged promise

Comment: Read the definition of the method - you can return a promise or observable, which Angular will then resolve for you before continuing.

Comment: I am aware of this but I need 2 conditions as the user can be authenticated anonymously

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the observable in your `canActivate`. You'll need something like this:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.afAuth.authState.map(auth => {
        if (isNullOrUndefined(auth)) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```